Нужна помощь/совет - Telegram бот
Написал код для бота в Telegram, в PyCharm все работает, ошибок нет и при запущенном коде на PyCharm в самом Telegram все тоже работает. Выгрузил на бесплатный хостинг PythonAnywhere, бот отвечает на команду /start, но не отвечает на какие-либо другие команды (переход на сайты в браузере).
Подскажите что следует сделать и где искать ошибку?

Бот асинхронный?

Да, бот асинхронный
